# Would a circle overlap a parabola's bottom by more than just its vertex?

Tags: circles, conic-sections

I mean, out of the condition that a circle actually crosses the parabola.
My question is when a circle is "inside" a parabola, would it touch part of the parabola other than just the parabola's vertex at the bottom?

So just the curiosity brought me crazy...but would this be possible?? (There was an image to show but my reputation is not enough since I'm a freshmeat :P)

Thanks xx

Comment: The question gets more interesting if you consider other "parabola-like" curves. How about $y=x^4$, for example, or $y=x^6$. On these curves, my guess is that there *can* be other contact points, in addition to the vertex (the point at the origin).

Comment: @bubba For $y=x^4$ there is one such circle, found by assuming its center is on $x=0$, then constructing normal lines from $(\pm a,a^4)$ and seeing where they meet $x=0$, and finally expressing that the threee distances from the center to the origin and to the points $(\pm a,a^4)$ all be equal. It turned out $a=(1/2)^{1/6}$ was forced, and the resulting circle stays above $y=x^4.$

Comment: @coffeemath -- Thanks. This seemed intuitively clear, for some $n$, because the curves get more "square" as $n$ increases. I thought it might be true for $n=4$ but was too lazy to work through the details. Nice to know that it's true. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equations for the circle and parabola. For simplicity, we'll have the circle centred at $(0,0)$, and the parabola tangent to the circle at $(0,-a)$, where $a$ is the radius of the circle.

From this, we have the equation
$$
x^2+y^2=a^2
$$
for the circle, and
$$
y=bx^2-a
$$
for the parabola. Now, if they coincide at any point, then the $x$ and $y$ values must be the same. So, substituting the second equation into the first one, we get
$$
x^2+(bx^2-a)^2=a^2
$$
or
$$
x^2+b^2x^4-2abx^2=0
$$
Now, at $x=0$, we have the "vertex" point, so we can assume that $x\neq 0$ for other solutions. This gives
$$
b^2x^2 = 2ab-1
$$
or
$$
x = \pm\frac{\sqrt{2ab-1}}b
$$
As such, if $2ab-1>0$, then there are more intersection points than just the vertex, given by
$$
\left(\pm\frac{\sqrt{2ab-1}}b,\frac{ab-1}b\right)
$$
If $2ab-1=0$, then the parabola follows the circle's trajectory in the vicinity of the vertex, but does not coincide. If $2ab-1<0$, then the "intersection points" occur at imaginary values, and thus do not exist in the reals.

Comment: The geometer in me forces me to add the comment that if we take the case $2ab=1$, the circle we get is the *osculating circle*, which is not only tangent to the parabola at $(0,-a)$ but also has precisely the same curvature. It intersects the parabola *only* at that one point, as the algebra above shows. (For the sophisticated, it has at least three-point contact with the parabola at the point and so, by symmetry, cannot intersect anywhere else.)

Comment: @TedShifrin: That would be the technical description in terms of geometry, yes. My wording was somewhat more basic intentionally.

Comment: Yes, I understand. You did magnificently. I just wanted to embellish :)

Answer (score 1):

We may assume the parabola is $y=x^2$, since by the similarity $x=kx',y=ky'$ this becomes $y'=kx'^2$ (all parabolas are similar), and the problem is the same if the plane is stretched by a magnification factor. Let the circle be centered at $(0,k)$ ($k>0$) and have radius $k$ so that it goes through the origin.

Only the lower half of the circle might intersect the parabola, and this lower half has equation
$$y=k-\sqrt{k^2-x^2}.$$
Now it is desired in the question that the circle lie "inside the parabola", which becomes that, for $-k \le x \le k$, we have
$$[1] \ \ k-\sqrt{k^2-x^2} \ge x^2.$$
This boils down to $x^2 \ge 2k-1$, where at one step we divided by $x^2$. This shows that we need exactly $k \le 1/2$ in order for the circle to lie above the parabola: If $k \le 1/2$ then $x^2 \ge 2k-1$ holds for all $x$, in particular on $[-k,k]$, while if $k>1/2$ there will be positive $x \in [-k,k]$ for which $x^2<2k-1$, against the circle lying above the parabola.

Now assume that indeed $k \le 1/2$. The condition that the lower semicircle meet the parabola at any point is [1] with equality, call that [1']. Only for $k=1/2$ is there a solution of $x^2=2k-1$ and it is at the origin, while if $k<1/2$ the equation $x^2=2k-1$ has no real solutions, and the circle only meets the parabola at the origin. (Recall the step in which division by $x^2$ made the $0$ drop out as a solution to [1'].)

So in conclusion if a circle lying above the parabola goes through the vertex, then it does not meet the parabola at any other points.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the circle, and on the parabola. If the parabola is very narrow, or the circle very large, then they'd meet at two points additionally to the vertex of the parabola. If the parabola is wide, or the circle small, they'd meet only at the vertex.