# Equivalence of definitions of topological skeleton

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

On the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton) of topological skeleton, it says

> One way of defining the skeleton of a shape A is as the set of centers
> of all maximal disks in A.
>
> ...
>
> The skeleton of a shape A can also be defined as the set of centers of
> the discs that touch the boundary of A in two or more locations.

In what sense are the two definitions equivalent?

Mathematically speaking, let $A$ be a open set.

Let $B$ be the set of the centers of maximal disks contained in $A$, where a maximal disk is a disk in $A$ that is not contained in any other disk in $A$.

Let $C$ be the set of the centers of disks that touch the boundary of $A$ in two or more points.

Surely $C \subset B$, as any circle $c$ strictly containing a circle in $C$ will contain a boundary point of $A$, therefore $c \not \subset A$.

**Question:** Is $C=B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think they are equal.

We show that there is a maximal disk that only intersects a boundary at one point. Consider the graph $P$ of a parabola $y=\frac{1}{2}x^2$, and let $A$ be everything in the plane that lies strictly above $P$.
The [Osculating Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osculating_circle) $S$ of the parabola $P$ at the point $(0,0)$ is the circle centered at $(0,1)$ with radius $1$ - so $S$ is the solution set to $x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$.
This circle $S$ is the boundary of a disk $D$, and intersects $P$ at only the point $(0,0)$ (see the picture pulled off [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OsculatingCircle.html)).

[image]

However, any disk $D'$ with larger radius than $D$, that contains $D$, must have a point that lies outside of $A\cup P$. The reason for this is, very vaguely speaking, that the curvature of $S$ and $P$ agree close to $(0,0)$. Any circle with larger radius curves less, and will 'bulge out' of the parabola.
There's an excellent discussion on the geometry of the osculating circle in the answers [to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397125/would-a-circle-overlap-a-parabolas-bottom-by-more-than-just-its-vertex).

It is however true that $C\subseteq B$, at least in two dimensions (it follows by a bit of triangle and circle geometry). I suspect $C\subseteq B$ no matter what the dimension, but I'm not confident I can prove it :P